# PcapPlusPlus Example- DPDKFilterTraffic not performing like I would expect, do I have something misconfigured?

Tags: pcapplusplus

I am working on an application that uses DPDK to write packet payloads to file and am investigating whether or not PcapPlusPlus could be used for this purpose. My setup is as follows:
[image]

I am using a Mellanox ConnectX-5 NIC, Ubuntu 22.04.01, and the latest DPDK and PcapPlusPlus. Kernel: 5.15.0-53-generic and 10 1GB hugepages.

Mellanox Connectx-5 NIC:

```
Device #1:
----------

  Device Type:      ConnectX5
  Part Number:      MCX516A-CCA_Ax
  Description:      ConnectX-5 EN network interface card; 100GbE dual-port QSFP28; PCIe3.0 x16; tall bracket; ROHS R6
  PSID:             MT_0000000012
  PCI Device Name:  /dev/mst/mt4119_pciconf0
  Base GUID:        b8cef60300fb1330
  Base MAC:         b8cef6fb1330
  Versions:         Current        Available     
     FW             16.35.1012     N/A           
     PXE            3.6.0804       N/A           
     UEFI           14.28.0015     N/A           

  Status:           No matching image found
```

Running ethtool on the card:

```
Settings for ens7f0np0:
        Supported ports: [ Backplane ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                40000baseKR4/Full
                                40000baseCR4/Full
                                40000baseSR4/Full
                                40000baseLR4/Full
                                25000baseCR/Full
                                25000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseSR/Full
                                50000baseCR2/Full
                                50000baseKR2/Full
                                100000baseKR4/Full
                                100000baseSR4/Full
                                100000baseCR4/Full
                                100000baseLR4_ER4/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: None        RS      BASER
        Advertised link modes:  100000baseKR4/Full
                                100000baseSR4/Full
                                100000baseCR4/Full
                                100000baseLR4_ER4/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: RS
        Speed: 100000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Port: Direct Attach Copper
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
netlink error: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000004 (4)
                               link
        Link detected: yes
```

Here is my issue. In the diagram, each link consists of two sets of packets. One set from port 0 and one set from port 1 etc. If using tcpdump I can record the packets from a single port without issue to a RAID0 array consisting of 4 NVME drives.

```
sudo tcpdump -i ens7f0np0 udp -nn -# -N -B 1048576 -t -q -Q in -p -w /mnt/md0/test/test.pcap dst port 50340
```

I get a .pcap file that is 2GB in size for a 1 second test as expected. Two ports is too much for the kernel so If I try to record everything I get dropped packets. This is where DPDK comes in. I wanted to use the DPDK filter example to do the same test with DPDK.

```
sudo ./DpdkTrafficFilter -d 2 -f /mnt/md0/ -o 'UDP' -c 7
```

I run the example and here is the output:

```
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 56
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 2
EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available 2048 kB hugepages reported
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1015) device: 0000:17:00.0 (socket 0)
mlx5_net: No available register for sampler.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1015) device: 0000:17:00.1 (socket 0)
mlx5_net: No available register for sampler.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:31:00.0 (socket 0)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:31:00.1 (socket 0)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1015) device: 0000:b1:00.0 (socket 1)
mlx5_net: No available register for sampler.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1015) device: 0000:b1:00.1 (socket 1)
mlx5_net: No available register for sampler.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1015) device: 0000:ca:00.0 (socket 1)
mlx5_net: No available register for sampler.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1015) device: 0000:ca:00.1 (socket 1)
mlx5_net: No available register for sampler.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1015) device: 0000:e3:00.0 (socket 1)
mlx5_net: No available register for sampler.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1015) device: 0000:e3:00.1 (socket 1)
mlx5_net: No available register for sampler.
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Opened device #2 with 1 RX queues and 1 TX queues. RSS hash functions:
   RSS_IPV4
   RSS_IPV6
Using core 1
   Core configuration:
      DPDK device#2: RX-Queue#0;  
Using core 2
   Core configuration:
      None
^C
Application stopped
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Core ID | Packet Cnt  | Eth Cnt     | ARP Cnt     | IPv4 Cnt    | IPv6 Cnt    | TCP Cnt     | UDP Cnt     | HTTP Cnt    | Matched TCP Flows  | Matched UDP Flows  | Matched Packets    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 514051      | 514051      | 0           | 514051      | 0           | 0           | 514051      | 0           | 0                  | 1                  | 514050             |
| 2       | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0                  | 0                  | 0                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Total   | 514051      | 514051      | 0           | 514051      | 0           | 0           | 514051      | 0           | 0                  | 1                  | 514050             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, the pcap file is only 725MB for a 1 second test! Any idea what I am doing wrong? Are packets being dropped? If so why is the performance worse than tcpdump?

Also, not sure if it matters, but the traffic I am receiving is MTU 9000. I did change the DpdkTrafficFilter code to set the mtu to 9000 but got the same results.

Comment: @adstra please update dpdk version, distro or os kernel, nic firmware, nic speed, pf or vf details. you are mentioning about `DpdkTrafficFilter `. I am not able to find the same in DPDK examples or app folder. So if this is an external or hosted project, share link to the code base and step to built. In order compare share the dpdk port info stats and xstats (using dpdk procinfo tool) too.

Comment: @VipinVarghese this question is tagged pcapplusplus and is specific to that library. For more information reference here: https://pcapplusplus.github.io/ . DPDKTrafficFilter is an example written in that library. I did include the DPDK version, the distro, the speed etc. above. I added more information on the NIC. Thanks.

Comment: your question header is `DpdKExample-FilterTraffic` instead it should have been `pcapplusplus - filter traffic`.

Comment: since it is community project, don't you agree you will getting the right help from PcapPlusPlus maintainers?

Comment: @VipinVarghese ah I see why it showed up as DPDK. Thought if I did not tag it as DPDK then it would be contained to the pcapplusplus community. I apologize.  I believe they can help me with this specific question.